# Thread pool in a web server in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, webserver, pool

I have my multithread web server and now i wish to implement a thread pool, however even after looking about it i don't get how can i do it in my code :(

Could someone help me get it better?
I really need to understand how what i read can be used here, because i don't see the connection and how that works.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class WebServer {

    static class RequisicaoRunnable implements Runnable {

        private Socket socket;

        RequisicaoRunnable(Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                //System.out.println("connection from " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostName());
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                //System.out.println("READING SOCKET...");
                String str = in.readLine();
                String[] arr = str.split(" ");
                if (arr != null && arr.length > 2) {
                    while(!str.equals("")) {
                        //System.out.println(str);
                        str = in.readLine();
                    }
                    if (arr[0].equals("GET")) {
                        //System.out.println("REQUESTED RESOURCE: " + arr[1]);
                        String nomeArquivo = arr[1];
                        if (arr[1].startsWith("/")) {
                            nomeArquivo = nomeArquivo.substring(1);
                        }
                        if (nomeArquivo.equals("")) {
                            nomeArquivo = "index.html";
                        }
                        File f = new File(nomeArquivo);
                        if (f.exists()) {
                            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(f);
                            socket.getOutputStream().write("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n\n".getBytes());
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                            int lidos;
                            do {
                                lidos = fin.read(buffer);
                                if (lidos > 0) {
                                    socket.getOutputStream().write(buffer, 0, lidos);
                                }
                            } while (lidos > 0);
                            fin.close();
                        } else {
                            socket.getOutputStream().write("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\n\n".getBytes());
                            socket.getOutputStream().write("<html><body>HTTP/1.0 404 File Not Found</body></html>\n\n".getBytes());
                        }
                    } else {
                        socket.getOutputStream().write("HTTP/1.0 501 Not Implemented\n\n".getBytes());
                    }
                }
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);
        System.out.println("waiting connections....");
        while (true) {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            RequisicaoRunnable req = new RequisicaoRunnable(socket);
            new Thread(req).start();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you are not using a framework for your server? i.e. Spring

Comment: @tmanion in this case i just made the very first web server. What would you suggest? :)

Comment: If this isn't for a class project and you're trying to make a website specifically in java, I would try reading into the Spring framework.  You can download a plugin for eclipse and get a well - programmed starting point for one! Otherwise if you are feeling adventurous look into the play framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea behind the `Thread pool` is that create a specified number of threads at start and then assign task to them. **Alternatively removing headache of creating threads each time.**
I was implemented it a little some days ago, here is what I done.

1. Create some threads at start they share a request queue
2. Threads are constantly looking for queue and when a request come one
   of the thread dispatch the request and perform action
3. The Queue will be synchronized 3.

Here are some queue methods

```
Queue#add();    //add the socket at the end
Queue#removeFront();//remove socket
Queue#isEmpty();//boolean if queue is empty
Queue#size(); //return size of queue
Queue#getMaxSize();//get maximum allowed size for queue
```

Your Request processing runnable

```
public class Processor implements Runnable {

    private Queue<Socket> requests;
    private boolean shut;

    Processor(Queue<Socket> requests) {
        this.requests = requests;
        shut = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(!shut) {
            if(requests.isEmpty()) {
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(#rendomeTimemill);
                } catch(InterruptedException e){}
            }else {
                Socket skt = Queue.removeFront();
                try {
                    //System.out.println("processing request from " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostName());
                    //do you want
                } catch (Exception e) {
                } finally {
                    if(skt != null) {
                        try{ skt.close(); skt = null; } catch(IOException ex){}

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void stopNow() {
        shut = true;
        Thread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

in your main thread
create a queue to put requests

```
//start your server socket
Queue<Socket> requests = new Queue<Socket>();
```

Start worker thread pool

```
Precessor []workers = new Processor[NUM_WORKER];
for(int i=0;i<NUM_WORKER; i++) {
    worker[i] = new Processor(requests);
    Thread th = new Thread(worker[i]);
    th.strat();
}
```

in request listening

```
//while loope that run forever
// accept socket
    if(requests.size() == requests.getMaxSize()) {
        socket.getOutputStream().write("HTTP/1.0 505 Error\n\n".getBytes());
        socket.getOutputStream().write("<html><body>Try again</body></html>\n\n".getBytes());
        socket.close();
    } else {
            requests.add(socket);
    }
```

when you want to shout down server

```
for(int i=0;i<NUM_WORKER; i++) {
    worker[i].stopNow();
}
```

**Note:** My concern was not the HTTP headers, so i m not specific, but you must implement the complete HTTP header e.g. Content-type, Content-length etc.

Comment: the consumer would have something special as well? Or i only worry with the producer?

Comment: @ShiroyamaCah consumer will serve the required request (read and write that page on `outputstream`. see `processor class`.

Answer (score 2):

JDK might be a good place to start
An Executor or ExecutorService should is what you're looking for. Reading material:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

The examples in there are pretty complete I think, but here's an example using the code you posted:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {




ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);
    System.out.println("waiting connections....");

    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

   while (true) {
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        RequisicaoRunnable req = new RequisicaoRunnable(socket);
        pool.execute(req);
    }
}
```

We create an executor service that is backed by a cached thread pool. You can swap this out for any type of pool you like by changing the type of executor service you get from Executors:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html

In the example I've given we use a cached thread pool which should create new threads as needed but re use old ones as they become available (finish whatever they were executing). If you look through the methods provided in that class you can create  Executor services that are backed by various types of thread pool e.g. single thread, fixed number of threads, etc.

The example above should work as is, but if you want to change how the thread pool works try another thread pool type.
The cached thread pool will mean each connection will immediately be serviced, however it can create an unbounded number of threads.

on the other hand if you wanted the executor to use a blocking queue as suggested by fge you could try a fixed thread pool instead:

```
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(x)
```

you get the blocking queue for free with that.

Comment: Sorry the question, because java is my second programming language and still new: in this case, i would still have more executor functions to apply in my code to have it working like i wish right? I get that the newCachedThreadPool() will help with the use and reuse of the threads, which is already a good thing to me, but do you have a preference? Like.... an executor that you would suggest as the better one in my case?

Comment: I think that example should work as is. if you have more classes implmenting Runnable you can execute those on the same Executor or create another one if you want more thread pools.

added a note on using a queue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use, for instance, a `BlockingQueue`. This is the basis for a producer/consumer scenario.

In your case:

- the producer holds the server socket; it accepts new client sockets and pushes the client sockets onto the queue;
- the consumers grab client sockets from the queue and process requests.

On top of all that, you can also use a *bounded* queue; you can try and push a new client socket to the queue; if the queue is full you can then default to a "no can't do" consumer.

Scenarios are many. There is not one answer.

Comment: I have a producer/consumer work already done(https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByARXuWndnxMZ1k5Y0NEcGFtSnc/edit?usp=sharing) however i'm really bad in understanding programming fast, that's why i normally research a lot and ask a lot to compensate. Do you believe that what i have of producer/consumer can work in my situation?

Comment: You are, imho, not doing it the correct way. Read my post carefully again. Your producer and consumer classes should be separated; but they should share a common queue.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the idea is simple enough.  You main loop currently creates a new RequisicaoRunnable object and a new Thread to run it each time it gets a connection from a client.  The idea behind a thread pool is to avoid creating new Threads each time.

In the simplest version of a thread pool, you create a blocking queue, and you create and start a fixed number of *worker threads* before you enter your main loop.  The main loop will look almost exactly the same as what you have now, but instead of starting a Thread to run each new RequisicaoRunnable, it will simply add the new object to the queue.

Your worker threads are all the same:
    while (! shutdownHasBeenRequested()) {
        RequisicaoRunnable requisicaoRunnable = getATaskFromTheQueue();
        requisicaoRunnable.run();
    }

That way, each new task (client) will be executed (handled) by the next available thread from your pool.

If this is a homework assignment then you'll pretty much want to implement what I described, filling in some details as needed.

If it's *not* homework, then consider using a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExcecutor() instead.  No point in re-inventing the wheel when there's a perfectly good wheel right there waiting to be used.

---

Edit: as fge said, one improvement would be to send back a quick "sorry, try again later" response when new connections are coming in faster than you can handle them.  When the queue has too many pending connections in it (i.e., when you hit the limit of a BoundedQueue), that's when you know to bail out and send the "try again later" response.

Comment: My main problem in programming is that i take a good while to get the idea, that's why i research a lot and ask a lot. Java is the second programming language i have and it's pretty new to me still, so sorry if what i'm going to ask is kinda obvious: how the creation of a blocking queue would work? I saw it but i can't see how could i make it in my code.

Comment: The Java standard libraries are open source, which means you can get the source and read it.  Have a look at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue or LinkedBlockingQueue for example.